# 301 Redirect old to New domain also non-www to www redirect (including index.php )

Tags: php, url, redirect, web

I have recently shift my old website to new name (Both website content and Space are same)

I want this 6 Permutation combination to happen due duplicate content policy of google :

1. quantumeducation.in to http://www.quantum.edu.in
2. www.quantumeducation.in to www.quantum.edu.in
3. quantumeducation/index.php to www.quantum.edu.in
4. www.quantumeducation.in/index.php to www.quantum.edu.in
   Also
5. quantum.edu.in to to www.quantum.edu.in
6. [www.quantum.edu.in/index.php](http://www.quantum.edu.in/index.php) to www.quantum.edu.in

Currently i m using this:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^quantumeducation.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.quantumeducation.in$

RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\://www.quantum.edu.in/" [R=301,L]

But It **can't solve Step 4, 5 & 6**

Any ideas why this wouldn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single regex in your rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(w{3}\.)?(quantumeducation\.in|quantum.edu.in)$
```

You shouldn't need to change the PHP files if the server-level redirect is working properly.

Comment: When i used like below my website go to loop:::::;


RewriteEngine on

AddType application/vnd.ms-excel11 xls

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(w{3}\.)?(quantumeducation\.in|quantum.edu.in)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.quantum\.edu\.in\/" [R=301,L]